bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile() in gradio function causing core dumped
(I also send a issue to blender developer, but I'm not quite sure if it's a bug or it's just my bad coding skill causing this problem, so I also ask the problem here for help.)
System Information
Operating system: Windows 10, Ubuntu 22.04
Graphics card: RTX 2080super(Windows 10), RTX 4090D(Ubuntu 22.04)
Blender Version
Broken: 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.3.0-beta, python module bpy
Short description of error
Got core dump both in Windows and Linux when placing bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile() in gradio function.
In Linux (bpy as python3.11 module):
root@mypc:~/shiki# python test.py 
                        * Running on local URL:  http://127.0.0.1:7860
                        To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
                        Read blend: "/root/shiki/testp.blend"
                        Segmentation fault (core dumped)

No crash file generated in this case.
In Windows (run test.py in blender):
* Running on local URL:  http://127.0.0.1:7860
To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
Read blend: "C:\Users\Shiki\Desktop\TmpRender\tst.blend"

Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address: 0x00007FF75E9C9270
Module: blender.exe
Thread: 0004e28c
Writing: C:\Users\Shiki\AppData\Local\Temp\script.crash.txt

script.crash.txt
test.py is shown here:
import gradio as gr
import bpy

## Set your blender file path here
blend_filepath = "/root/shiki/testp.blend"
## For Windows, blend_filepath = "C:\\Users\\Shiki\\Desktop\\TmpRender\\tst.blend"


## When bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile is placed here, everything goes well.
## bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_filepath)

def read():
    ## When bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile is placed here, core dumped.
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_filepath)
    fps = str(bpy.context.scene.render.fps)
    res = str(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x) + "*" + str(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y)
    info = "FrameRate: " + fps + "\n" + "Resolution: " + res
    return info



with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    read_blend_file = gr.Button("Read Your Blender File")
    file_info_box = gr.Textbox(label="File Info")
    
    read_blend_file.click(fn=read, outputs=file_info_box)


demo.launch() 

test.py
Exact steps for others to reproduce the error
For Linux (Python3.11):
pip install bpy
pip install gradio
python test.py

Open 127.0.0.1:7860 in browser and click "Read Your Blender File", then python will crash without crash log.
For Windows:
Pip install gradio for blender's bundled Pythonblender-***/4.**/python/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade gradio
Run test.py in Blender
Open 127.0.0.1:7860 in browser and click "Read Your Blender File", then Blender will crash.
